# How to turn the following `.click` into a toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code:

```
  $('.ask-button').click(function() {
    $('.wpcf7-form').hide()
    $(this).css('margin-left', 0)
  })
```

I know I can't just do `.toggle` because in order to restore `margin-left` I have to include the original value (`300px`).

What's the simplest way to turn the event above into a toggle?

Comment: give some fiddle link, it will be easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.toggle()` to show hide the element and use `.toggleClass()` for toggling class with css margin left set to 0:

```
$('.ask-button').click(function() {
  $('.wpcf7-form').toggle()
  $(this).toggleClass('marginzero');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.marginzero{
   margin-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTML
   <button class="ask-button">ask</button>
<div class="wpcf7-form">Sample text<div>
    js
  $('.ask-button').click(function() {
    $('.wpcf7-form').toggleClass('wpcf8-form')
  })
    css
   .wpcf7-form{ margin-left:300px; border:1px solid #ddd}
.wpcf8-form{ margin-left:0; border:1px solid #ddd}
```

use this link define width in class. it works

Comment: `.css` won't make the margin `300px` when pressed again.

Comment: i changed css and js. try this one